# URL Title and Structure Listing URL

Tags: structure

Does ExpressionEngine automatically generate the URL Title and Structure listing URL as the same when the Title for the page is entered?

Do both URL Title and Structure listing URL have to be the same or optional?

When the URL Title or page title is modified, Why EE doesn't update the Structure listing URL automatically?

Answer (score 1):

1.) Yes it does. Unless another entry with the same url-title or structure title, then ee throws an error or appends a number to the title

2.) they do not have to be the same

3.) Because the structure js only modifies the structure title when the title field is updated. You can use a plugin like http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js to bind an onchange event to the url title

Comment: Does EE use only the Structure listing ULR to display the page?

Comment: No it doesn't. I typically use entry_id="{structure:page:entry_id}" in a detail paged entry if it's controlled by Structure if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

We just posted to Devot-ee.com our add-on that forces the URL Title field to match the Structure Page/Listing URL field.

View "URL Title Match" here: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/url-title-match